# Javascript - WebSocket OnOpen event not triggering

Tags: c#, javascript, html, firefox, websocket

I keep getting an error whenever I try to use this JS code to connect to my WebSocket server on my computer:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ws;
    try{
        if("WebSocket" in window){   
                ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:50002"); 
                socket.onopen = function(){  
                    $('#topbar').empty();
                    $('#topbar').append('<form id="test">');
                    $('#topbar').append('<input>');
                    $('#topbar').append('</form>');

                }  

                socket.onmessage = function(msg){  
                    ;  
                }  

                socket.onclose = function(){  
                    ;  
                } 

                socket.onerror = function(error){
                    $('#topbar').append('<div>Cannot make a connection with the server. Server is most likely in maintenance mode. Try again later</div>');
                }
        }
    }
    catch(exception) {$('#topbar').append('<div>Cannot make a connection with the server. Server is most likely in maintenance mode. Try again later</div>');}

});
```

I run this code in Firefox, but when I trace my code, the Catch event is triggered instead of OnOpen, and I get this message:

> [11:58:50.103]  The connection to ws://localhost:50002/ was
>   interrupted while the page was loading.  @ /lib/default.js:5

I know this is a bug in Firefox, but my Server Console keeps saying it's accepted a connection from my computerr 127.0.0.1. Am I missing something? I'm using Fleck server in C#

Comment: BUMP. Any help with this? It's been almost a week now...

Comment: BUMP. Two weeks now. Doesn't anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: BUMP i would also like to know this(a little late)

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot provide an answer for your server issue, on line 6 you immediately invoke a variable (`socket`) which doesn't exist yet, and continue to use that throughout your script. This would actually cause, at the very least, your `catch` to be triggered, as it would produce an exception.

Replace the instances of `socket` with `ws` (or vice versa) and let's see where that gets us.